# Insert from one table to another and replace the values

Tags: sql, sql-insert

So there's two tables Table1 and Table2. Please refer to the screenshot [image: screenshot] attached for reference to Table1 structure and values. Notice that Row #5 has all NULL values.

I was trying to pick up values from Table1 (ONLY IF IT'S NOT NULL), replace those values with hard-coded value of '**Override**' and insert them into Table 2.

So ideally, Table2 should look like the screenshot

[image: screenshot2]

attached. Notice that row #5 was NOT inserted because it had all NULL values.

I've written the query below but it inserts the hard-coded value for both columns no matter what the value is and table looks like the screenshot

[image: screenshot3]

attached. Please refer below for the query and assist.

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (Row_Number, ValueA, ValueB)
SELECT Row_Number, ValueA= 'Override', ValueB= 'Override' FROM Table A
WHERE A.ValueA is not null
or ValueB is not null ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `case` expression :

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (Row_Number, ValueA, ValueB)
    SELECT Row_Number, 
           (case when ValueA is not null then 'Override' end) as ValueA, 
           (case when ValueB is not null then 'Override' end) as ValueB
    FROM Table A
    WHERE A.ValueA is not null or ValueB is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
INSERT 
INTO        Table_2
            (Row_Number,ValueA, ValueB)
SELECT      Row_Number,
            CASE
            WHEN A.valueA IS NOT NULL THEN
                'Override'
            END AS ValueA, 
            CASE
            WHEN A.ValueB IS NOT NULL THEN
                'Override'
            END AS ValueB
FROM        Table_1 A
WHERE       A.ValueA IS NOT NULL
        OR  A.ValueB IS NOT NULL
```